# How to encode an array as a http get parameter?

Tags: python, twitter, python-requests, http-get

My goal is to send an API request with an array as a parameter value. The request-URL is `https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?max_results=100&tweet.fields=lang,created_at&query=%23test`.When I'm using the URL as a string it works.

However, since it's more convenient to work with a dictionary of arguments I wanted to use the syntax `response = requests.request('GET', url, headers=header, params=params)` as it allows me to set all the parameters within a single object.

For this, my parameter dictionary looks like this.

```
params = {
    "max_results": 100,
    "tweet.fields": ["lang","created_at"],
    "query": "%23test"
}
```

The problem here is the resulting URL `https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?max_results=100&tweet.fields=lang&tweet.fields=created_at&query=%23test`.

This URL won't work as `tweet.fields` is encoded with `tweet.fields=lang&tweet.fields=created_at` which **violates the duplicate parameter policy** of Twitter.

```
'{"errors":[{"parameters":{"tweet.fields":["lang","created_at"]},"message":"Duplicate parameters are not allowed:  the `tweet.fields` query parameter"}],"title":"Invalid Request","detail":"One or more parameters to your request was invalid.","type":"https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/invalid-request"}'
```

Another idea was to change the parameters to `"tweet.fields": {"lang","created_at"},` which results in the same URL as the other parameter dictionary.

How would I encode the parameter in a way that the parameter will be encoded as `tweet.fields=lang,created_at` rather than `tweet.fields=lang&tweet.fields=created_at` while keep using the parameter dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a string like `lang, created_at` then simply place one there.

```py
params = {
    "max_results": 100,
    "tweet.fields": "lang,created_at",
    "query": "%23test"
}
```

You can also automatically generate one with `.join` method.

```py
params = {
    "max_results": 100,
    "tweet.fields": ",".join(["lang", "created_at"]) ,
    "query": "%23test"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought, that it wouldn't work as it encodes it as `tweet.fields=lang%2Ccreated_at` but it seems like they're decoding the `%2` again.